# is "from in her eyes" correct?

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I just saw a quote by Audrey Hepburn that says "The beauty of a woman must be seen from in her eyes, because that is the doorway to her heart, the place where love resides."
I wonder is "from in her eyes" correct? why not just saying "in her eyes"?
are there any differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a prepositional phrase as a prepositional complement is not uncommon, especially when the first preposition is 'from'. [See [CDO_English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prepositional-phrases)]

*Please wait until after the service.*

*The noise came from behind the door.*

*The cat ran out from under the sofa.*

*True beauty comes from within the heart.*

However, here the utterance doesn't make sense, at least on the surface.

> The beauty of a woman must be seen coming from within her eyes ...

shows that the beauty is to be seen **coming** from within (or via) the eyes, rather than seen from the woman's viewpoint ('seen from within her eyes'). A less confusing and more acceptable deletion gives

> The beauty of a woman must/can only truly be seen in her eyes...

Comment: There is some doubt as to whether Hepburn actually used *from*. The quote appears with and without that preposition -- possibly as a result of editorialisation as you suggest here. [Example](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/692403.Audrey_Hepburn): the quote would work with either *from* **or** *in,* but struggles with both.

Answer (score 0):

"The beauty of a woman must be seen ***by looking into her eyes***

, because that is the doorway to her heart, the place where love resides."

Answer (score 0):

"The beauty of a woman must be seen **through**  her eyes

, because that is the doorway to her heart, the place where love resides."